# dynamically populating dictionary with multiple strings

Tags: python, string, dictionary

this is do be done in Python

I have this list.

```
['arst', 'abt', 'arst', 'art', 'abrt', 'aprty', 'abt', 'arst']
```

I want to put this in a dictionary such that all matching strings go under 1 key (same number of times as they appear in above list), say:

```
dict = { 'arst': ['arst', 'arst', 'arst'], 'abt' : ['abt', 'abt] and so on ...
```

How to add multiple strings to one key dynamically ?

Comment: Why not just build a counter? - `collections.Counter(my_list)`. The output format doesn't seem greatly useful to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['arst', 'abt', 'arst', 'art', 'abrt', 'aprty', 'abt', 'arst']

dct = {k: [k] * v for k, v in Counter(lst).items()}
# {'arst': ['arst', 'arst', 'arst'], 
#  'abt': ['abt', 'abt'], 
#  'art': ['art'], 
#  'abrt': ['abrt'], 
#  'aprty': ['aprty']}
```

Comment: Pls dont copy answers in SO

Comment: I highly doubt someone with ~50K points would copy an answer. Please don't make baseless accusations.

Comment: You might notice that we posted at just about the same time. I certainly have never copied an answer :) If you removed your ugly "repeated calls to `list.count` approach" I'd even given you an upvote.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yea, i'll remove it cuz i isint suitable for larger lists

Answer (score 0):

Or using the `Counter` module:

```
from collections import Counter
result = {k:[k]*v for k,v in Counter(l).items()}
```

gives:

```
{'abt': ['abt', 'abt'], 'abrt': ['abrt'], 'aprty': ['aprty'], 'art': ['art'], 'arst': ['arst', 'arst', 'arst']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a loop to get the desired result, Use:

```
d = {}
for item in lst: # lst = ['arst', 'abt', 'arst', 'art', 'abrt', 'aprty', 'abt', 'arst']
    if item in d:
        d[item].append(item)
    else:
        d[item] = [item]

print(d)
```

This resulting dictionary `d` would be:

```
{'arst': ['arst', 'arst', 'arst'], 'abt': ['abt', 'abt'], 'art': ['art'], 'abrt': ['abrt'], 'aprty': ['aprty']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function for converting any list into dictionary with same data grouped together

```
def Convert(lst): 
    res_dct={}
    for i in set(lst):
        res_dct[i]=[i]*(lst.count(i))

    return res_dct 

lst = ['arst', 'abt', 'arst', 'art', 'abrt', 'aprty', 'abt', 'arst']

print(Convert(lst))
```